# Enumerating Sub-Folder Properties with VBscript

Tags: vbscript, directory, filesystemobject

This is somewhat related to Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2007, but it's really about an issue with VBScript, the FileSystemObject API and reading sub-folder properties.

I am trying to run a script to enumerate the folders and folder sizes on one of our Distribution Points (every folder beneath the Package Share). I'm using the FileSystemObject API, with VBscript, I can crawl about 60% of the sub-folders, and get their names and sizes, but then the rest return "error 70 / Permission Denied".  It doesn't matter what account I execute the script as, and I've tried adding a Sleep() delay between each sub-folder object reference. It still won't get them all.

If I manually explore the folders, I can view their properties without any problem.  Is this a known issue with FSO or maybe Windows Scripting Host?  I've attached the script code below.  TIA!

```
'****************************************************************
' Filename..: fso_subfolder_sizes.vbs
' Author....: skatterbrainz
' Date......: 02/10/2013
' Purpose...: enumerate package folders and tally disk space
'****************************************************************
Option Explicit

Const rootFolder = "\\SERVER123\ShareName$"

Dim time1, folderCount, totalSpace
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objSub
Dim GBsize, folderName, folderSIze

time1 = Timer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folderCount = 0
totalSpace = 0

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(rootFolder)

If err.Number = 0 Then

    wscript.echo "<folders>"

    For each objSub in objFolder.SubFolders

        folderName = objSub.Name
        folderSize = objSub.Size

        GBsize = FormatNumber(Bytes2Gbytes(folderSize), 2) & " GB"

        wscript.echo "<folder name=""" & folderName & """ size=""" & GBsize & """/>"

        folderCount = folderCount + 1
        totalSpace = totalSpace + folderSize

    Next

    Set objFolder = Nothing

    wscript.echo "</folders>"

    wscript.echo "--------------------------"
    wscript.echo "sub-folders: " & folderCount
    wscript.echo "total space: " & FormatNumber(Bytes2GBytes(totalSpace),2) & " GB"
Else
    wscript.echo "root folder not found"
End If

Set objFSO = Nothing

wscript.echo "runtime: " & FormatNumber(Timer - time1, 2) & " Msecs"

Function Bytes2Gbytes(n)
    If n > 0 Then
        Bytes2Gbytes = (n / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    Else
        Bytes2Gbytes = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I somehow doubt that the above is the actual code you're running, because the `On Error Resume Next` would make the script fail silently without any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a known issue, on folders with security issues (like eg your c:\windows folder) you get errors when you use .count of .size on folder. Instead enumerate each file and sum the count and size.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to get profile size of each UserProfile from a share. I used excel and was looping through rows with usernames that I knew had a profile in the share, like this:

```
strUserName = ActiveCell.Value
objP = "\\SERVER\SHARE$\" & strUserName & "\UPM_Profile"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = (FormatNumber(objFSO.GetFolder(objP).Size, 0, , , 0) / 1024) / 1024
```

Just some of the thousands folders gave "Path Not Found"
It all worked when I instead mapped the Share to a driveletter:

```
objP = "Z:\" & strUserName '& "\UPM_Profile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting, yet reproducible behavior with this topic.  At least in our production environment:  If I specify the root path as the root hidden share (i.e. "\SERVER\Share$") it gets really bogged down.  But if I go one level deeper, such as "\SERVER\Share$\Apps") it seems to run much better.  I also modified the script to print the sub-folder name first, and THEN query the .Size property, and that seems to point to the performance bottleneck.  Note the change in statement ordering in the updated example below...

```
    For each objSub in objFolder.SubFolders

    folderName = objSub.Name

    wscript.echo vbTab & "<folder>"
    wscript.echo vbTab & vbTab & "<folderName>" & folderName & "</folderName>"

    folderSize = objSub.Size
    GBsize = FormatNumber(Bytes2Gbytes(folderSize), 2) & " GB"

    wscript.echo vbTab & vbTab & "<folderSize>" & GBsize & "</folderSize>"
    wscript.echo vbTab & "</folder>"

    folderCount = folderCount + 1
    totalSpace = totalSpace + folderSize

Next
```

Comment: vbscript is extremely slow in enumerating networkfolders, see my question here with samples in some languages, eg vbscript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138160/benchmarks-does-python-have-a-faster-way-of-walking-a-network-folder